# Swift - ViewController over Split View

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, swift2

Hey anyone who knows how to implement a ViewController over Split View.
I want this to be shown only on first launch of the app I know how to do it when is launched for first time with NSUserDefaults but, I don't know how to positioning over the split view.

Comment: With NSUserDefaults? I don't understand...

Comment: just tell me how to display UIViewControler over the split view

Comment: Use a UIPresentationController.